# How to find the average of full column by grouping specified values in mysql

Tags: mysql

In my database i have tables in this format

```
 User           Values            Avg(Values)
  1               x1
  2               x2                  y1
  3               x3
  4               x4

  5               x5
  6               x6                  y2
  7               x7
  8               x8
  .                .
  .                .
  n               xn
```

I have to find the average of values for first 4 users separately that is from x1-x4 and next 4 users separately x5-x8 and display the average of first 4 user and next 4 users in Avg(Values) column as y1 and y2 etc.

How can i query it in mysql?

Please suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FLOOR((user-1)/4)+1 AS y, AVG(values) AS AvgValues
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY y
```

Dividing the user number by 4 will put them in groups of that size. We have to subtract 1 because the user numbers start at 1 rather than 0. Then we add 1 after dividing to get the group numbers back to starting from 1.

Comment: Imagine that i user 1 has  values x1,x2,x3,x4 and the same user 1 has values again x5, x6,x7,x8, i have to find out the avg for the same user separately and display it in column as avg(x1,x2,x3,x4) as y1 and avg(x5,x6,x7,x8) as y2.

Comment: Please show some real data in the question and the result that it should produce.

Answer (score 0):

I have two columns named s_id and cpm, in which i have values as

s_id(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2.......7,7,7,7,7,7) like wise i have ten values for each s_id and i have corresponding cpm values as (0.000,32.738,0.000,13.423,16.692........etc) I have to find the average of CPM for each ten values of s_id 1,2,3 etc and display it in column separately as average of cpm

s_id     CPM
  1     0.000
  1     32.738
  1     0.000
  1     13.423
  1     16.692
  1     30.303
  1     0.000
  1     28.881
  1     0.000
  1     29.255
  1     0.000
  1     31.847
  1     0.000
  1     21.142
  1     0.000
  1     20.179
  1     0.000
  1     37.037
  1     0.000
  1     20.761
  1     0.000
  1     5.098
  1     26.549
  1     26.667
  1     0.000
  1     9.554
  1     0.000
  1     34.014
  1     0.000
  1     30.769
  1     0.000
  1     4.818
  1     0.000
  1     13.732
  1     0.000
  1     26.804
  1     0.000
  1     28.078
  1     0.000
  1     33.333
  2     12.533
  2     4.875
  2     26.897
  2     19.512
  2     26.281
  2     21.710
  2     18.194
  2     8.582
  2     15.286
  2     25.986
  3     33.588
  3     36.036
  3     25.166
  3     10.839
  3     30.195
  3     32.051
  3     32.609
  3     33.981
  3     38.348
  3     27.895
  4     38.128
  4     14.563
  4     24.958
  4     23.468
  4     32.609
  4     29.624
  4     26.886
  4     29.499
  4     28.133
  4     34.435
  5     35.222
  5     30.402
  5     21.459
  5     29.181
  5     37.709
  5     29.526
  5     32.051
  5     35.313
  5     29.348
  5     35.553
  6     30.110
  6     25.496
  6     40.161
  6     33.451
  6     33.333
  6     30.020
  6     23.874
  6     43.478
  6     35.147
  6     35.019
  7     39.381
  7     40.369
  7     32.668
  7     30.249
  7     41.290
  7     48.558
  7     30.956
  7     41.783
  7     27.732
  7     26.822